# How does knockout create functions from property bindings?

Tags: javascript, knockout.js

When I set a knockout binding property as some javascript statement how is knockout able to wrap it in a function?

[image: Statement gets wrapped in a function]

If I create an object like so:

```
var myObject = {
    'text': Data.Info.Title()
};
```

The text property is going to be set with the value of title. How could I get this to be a function instead?

Comment: getters and setters perhaps?

Comment: @jfriend00 - Can you give me an example?

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Working_with_Objects#Defining_getters_and_setters

Comment: I suspect knockout takes the binding string and if it recognizes it as a property of the viewmodel (possibly prefixed with !) then it binds to that property, otherwise it wraps whatever it's passed in a function.

Comment: Is this a question about knockout's internals, or is there something specific you're trying to accomplish?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your binding, it works because knockout parses the binding, which is not the case in your second example.

> The text property is going to be set with the value of title. How could I get this to be a function instead?

Simply remove the parenthesis:

```
var myObject = {
    'text': Data.Info.Title
};
```

Works also on the binding:

```
<span data-bind="text: Data.Info.Titleasdasdasd"></span>
```